# Passing an NSMutableArray to another object in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsmutablearray

I'm making a network call and retrieving some information from an API and storing it in an `NSMutableArray`. I hit a wall when trying to send that array info over to another object:
I don't have any errors. I am not able to access the array information in another class. It prints fine in the API class but when trying to access in another class the array prints empty.

This is my API class with an `NSMutableArray` at the very top to hold the info:

```
class API: NSObject {

    var informationArray = NSMutableArray();

    func getEarthquakeInformation() {

        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let urlString = "http://ehp2-earthquake.wr.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&limit=20"
        let url = NSURL(string: urlString)!
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request){ data,response,downloadError in

            if let error = downloadError {
                 print("could not complete the request\(error)")
            } else {

                let parsedResult = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data! , options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments)
                let dataDict = parsedResult as! NSDictionary

                // This holds all the information we need from the API.
                if let result = dataDict["features"] {

                    for var i = 0; i < result.count; i++ {
                        self.informationArray.addObject(result[i])
                        print(self.informationArray[i]) 
                    }

                } else {
                    print("error")
                }

                //print("info from the array \(self.informationArray)")   
            }  
        }
        task.resume() 
    }
}
```

And this is the class I'm trying to send it over to: MapViewController

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Instance of the api class
        let apiObject = API()
        apiObject.getEarthquakeInformation()
        print(apiObject.informationArray)
```

Comment: Your call (NSURLSession thing) is async. You'd print "print(apiObject.informationArray)" before "print(self.informationArray[i])". Use a block (closure I think in Swift)

Comment: What's the problem? What's the wall that you hit?

Comment: What is the error or print output?

Comment: i dont have any errors. I am not able to access the array information in another class. it prints fine in the api class but when trying to access in another class the array prints empty.

Comment: Please clarify your question or run the risk of deletion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  let apiObject = API()
    // Your problem it here this method takes time to update informationArray
    apiObject.getEarthquakeInformation()
    // But this line print immediately while it's still empty.
    print(apiObject.informationArray)
```

what you do is

- remove `informationArray` from the `API` class at all and put it in `MapViewController`
- change `getEarthquakeInformation` method to have a compeletion handler

  ```
  class API: NSObject {

  // remove it  //var informationArray = NSMutableArray();

  func getEarthquakeInformation(compeletion: (informationArray: [AnyObject]!) ->()) {

      let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
      let urlString = "http://ehp2-earthquake.wr.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&limit=20"
      let url = NSURL(string: urlString)!
      let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
      let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request){ data,response,downloadError in

          if let error = downloadError {
               print("could not complete the request\(error)")
          } else {

              let parsedResult = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data! , options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments)
              let dataDict = parsedResult as! NSDictionary

              // This holds all the information we need from the API.
              if let result = dataDict["features"] {
                compeletion(result)
              } else {
                  print("error")
              }
          }    
      }

      task.resume()
  }
  ```

and then in `MapViewController`

```
var informationArray: [AnyObject]!
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

    // Instance of the api class
    let apiObject = API()
    apiObject.getEarthquakeInformation() { [unowned self] (result) ->() in 
    self.inforamtionArray = result
    print(self.informationArray)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Several things here:

**First**, please look into using a networking library (such as [AlamoFire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire))

**Second**, when you declare your mutable array, you should do it in this form (No reason to use NSMutableArray()):

```
var myArray = [ObjectType]()
```

**Third**, don't use C-style for-loops, they're flagged to be removed from Swift. You should iterate instead:

```
for item in result {
    //Do something with item.
}
```

**Also**, as far as "sending" the array to your MapViewController object.
If the API object lives in your MapViewController, then you could have your API function take in a closure as an argument. You can pass the array back to the MapViewController in the closure itself.
Or you could also use notifications.

Hope this helps.